# Update one value Python SQLite without effecting others

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to update a SQLite table value without changing the rest. I tried this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s)")
```

It didn't work obviously and tried to Google it and I looked all over StackOverflow, but couldn't find a definite answer.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you elaborate it better?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I have two spots for values in the table but I only want to input values into one of them from pysqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. Something like

```
UPDATE test
SET Value1 = 'Foo'
WHERE Value1 = 'Bar' and Value2 = 'Baz'
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp